# bash "2>" not working turns to "2 >"

Tags: io-redirection, tcsh

For some reason whenever I try to redirect errors to file using `2>` it doesn't work and I get a message that treats the '2' and '>' as separate.

Strangely enough, when I press the up arrow to return to the previous command an extra space is added so that `2>` becomes `2 >` even though this is not what I wrote.

For example, if I type:

```
rm dir1 2> err1
```

It doesn't forward the error to the file.
When I press the up arrow the line turns into:

```
rm dir1 2 > err1
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights regarding this quite strange issue.
Thanks

Comment: You're not using bash.

Comment: when i write "which bash" I get "/bin/bash"
when I write echo $SHELL I get "tcsh"

Comment: @Ron [which](http://man.cx/which) bash tells you only where is bash, not the current shell in use

Answer (score 0):

You're not using bash according to your comment, in tcsh you can't redirect only one standard stream to a file, but you can redirect all the streams at once by using `>&` like so

```
rm dir >& outputfile1
```

[See this answer for more info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35715/stderr-redirection-not-working-in-csh)

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing to bash by "chsh -s /bin/bash" but got "Insecure dependency in system while running setuid at /usr/local/etc/acct.new/acct_admin line 45. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try calling ```/bin/bash``` directly to get bash for this session only. If that doesn't work you may need to contact your sysadmin about supporting bash. Still csh redirection should work because ```rm``` is silent, please **do** try ```rm dir1 >& output.file``` before trying to fumble with bash.

Comment: @Ron add some enviroment info: such as OS Type. By the way it may possible to change in the [/etc/passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd) file the default shell for some user.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use "bash" since it is for a class. My terminal was supposed to be bash, maybe it is an error the admin needs to fix... I don't know the exact OS of the terminal except that it is Linux..